Yangdump from OpenYuma does not generate handler in .c files for netconfd SIL code
I am trying to compile SIS code for the OpenYuma netconfd project from yang models. I am faced with the problem that a large number of models use extern augment. And the generated C files do not create the necessary handlers for such models.
я скачал исходники по этой ссылке https://github.com/OpenClovis/OpenYuma и собрал по инструкции. Затем я вызвал yangdump fromat=c module=foo
For example, have yang file with something like this content
grouping  foo-grouping {

        container foo {
            container config {
                presence "Configure foo";
                
                uses foo-config;
            } // END of config-container definition.

            container state {
                config false;
            
                uses foo-config;
            } // END of state-container definition.

            container foo-ports {
            
                uses foo-ports-top;
            } // END of foo-ports-container definition.

            uses evc-top;
        } // END of bridge-container definition.
    } // END of bridge-grouping definition.

    augment /baz:bars/baz:bar {
        when " /baz:bars/baz:bar/baz:type = '2' ";

        uses foo-grouping;
    }

yangdump does not generate handlers (in .c files) for attributes in containers foo-port-top, evc-top, foo-config
